# GLSL uber shaders preprocessing

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

In "uber shaders" sometimes it is necessary to exclude some calculations to configure material properties. For example in the phong lighting shader normal map is not always required and all the related code must be excluded somehow.

For glsl shaders preprocessing it is possible to use `#ifdef` directive and append some `#define` directives on top of the shaders code depending on what part of shader code must be excluded. Such code style looks a little verbose and introduces additional complexity and requirements.

For my glsl programs I use another preprocessing approach when glsl vertex and fragment shader sources are parsed and some specified identifiers (attribute, uniform, varying and local variable names) are cut from the program with all code lines that depend on them.

Is my approach acceptable, does it have name? Or there is some more correct way of solving this problem?

Comment: There is no "correct" way. There's whatever way you want. Many programs assemble GLSL source from fragments, do `source.replace(...)`, whatever it takes. TL;DR: Your way is fine

Comment: your approach is a variant of "automatic code generation" ("automatic code deletion"?) and is quite fine as far as I'm concerned. Keep up the good work!